# Ubuntu 18.04 resolution flickers after changing to a custom resolution with xrandr

Tags: gnome, xorg, gnome-shell, display-resolution, xrandr

So, after trying to change the resolution to 1024x576 (which is a custom resolution) by running these commands:
`cvt 1024 576 60`

`xrandr --newmode "1024x576_60.00"   46.50  1024 1064 1160 1296  576 579 584 599 -hsync +vsync`

`xrandr --addmode VGA1 "1024x576_60.00"`

And then i change it at "Settings > Display > Resolution"

But for some reason it either changes back to default resolution (1024x768), or flickers like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNHQh.jpg when i am connected via screensharing (VNC), and goes black on monitor.

When it flickers or has no signal i can change it back only by rebooting or `pkill -HUP gnome-shell` and at this point I have no idea what might be causing it. I thought it might be the high resolution i was trying before (1080p), but at 1024x576 i have no clue how i can change it to a custom resolution.
I even tried modifying/deleting monitors.xml but didnt work.

For some reason running killall -3 gnome-shell just after switching resolution will sometimes do the trick and the resolution will stay at the custom one.

Comment: For some reason running `killall -3 gnome-shell` just after switching resolution will sometimes do the trick and the resolution will stay at the custom one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest I could get was creating a script and then executing it with a desktop launcher after each time I login:

```
#!/bin/bash
xrandr --newmode "1280x720_60.00"   74.50  1280 1344 1472 1664  720 723 728 748 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode VGA1 "1280x720_60.00"
xrandr --output VGA1 --mode 1280x720_60.00 && killall -3 gnome-shell
```

Any other better solutions are welcomed